# Error 403 while cloning submodule via submodule update --init --recursive --remote

Tags: git, jenkins, github, git-submodules

I have two jenkins job to build for two different versions basically both build are identical apart from github repository branch but still one job is working perfectly while other is giving error.

After running command `submodule update --init --recursive --remote` by jenkins console prints

```
fatal: unable to access 'github link to submodule': The requested URL returned error: 403
fatal: clone of 'github link to submodule' into submodule path 
Failed to clone 'content from submodule file'. Retry scheduled
```

How one job is working while other is returning error and aborting.

Comment: You need to look at your ".gitmodules " file in the root of your repo for the branch which is failing and ensure the user cloning the repo got access to it.

Comment: Thanks, can you add this as in answer

Comment: sure, thank you. Please accept and upvote too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at your ".gitmodules " file in the root of your repo for the branch which is failing and ensure the user cloning the repo got access to it.

Comment: I had issue because in older version submodule was using https based url in .gitmodules while in jenkins machine ssh was used.

Comment: great, glad it was sorted.